# JOIN tables to get unique matches

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Let's say I'm having a table named ***orders*** which cointains items that have been ordered and, on the other side, a table named ***inventory*** containing every item I have. What I wish to do is to build a query that finds unique matches for every ordered item if there is something in inventory and never get a duplicate from the ***inventory*** table.

For some technical reasons that doesn't show in this simplified example, every item in inventory, even if it's the same, has it's own row in the ***inventory*** table.

```
ORDERS             INVENTORY
+----+---------+   +----+---------+
| id | item_id |   | id | item_id |
|----+---------|   |----+---------|
|  1 | 2       |   |  1 | 3       |
|  2 | 2       |   |  2 | 3       |
|  3 | 3       |   |  3 | 2       |
|  4 | 3       |   |  4 | 2       |
|  5 | 4       |   |  5 | 2       |
+----+---------+   +----+---------+
```

QUERY :

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.item_id, i.id AS inventory_id 
FROM orders o 
    INNER JOIN inventory i ON i.item_id = o.item_id 
WHERE 1
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
| order_id | item_id | inventory_id |
+----------+---------+--------------+
|        1 |       2 |            3 |
|        2 |       2 |            4 |
|        3 |       3 |            1 |
|        4 |       3 |            2 |
+----------+---------+--------------+
```

Every row must have a different value in the inventory_id column and nothing should be returned if there is no match.

I've been reading about INNER JOIN and DISTINCT in many many posts but I haven't found anything I could use.

Comment: I am bangin my head on the table here but I dont think these tables make any logical sense

Comment: You sample  is not clear  .. try explain better  ..

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is a simplified example for the sake of this question. The real tables contains dozens of columns and the real query is very long and complex. Still, if this works, my problem is solved.

Comment: This is backward-iterative task (next step may alter the result of previous step) which must be solved not at SQL level.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. I'll try this

Comment: Explain why `(4,2)` record from Inventory is selected and `(5,2)` is not, why not backward? or maybe `(3,2)` may be skipped?